# Multiple criteria within a single SHOULD query block

Tags: node.js, elasticsearch

I'm hooking into an API which I have no control over and would like to extract all *recipe* entries which match certain criteria. For the most part, this is a simple *'does value equal N'*, however for one of these criterion I also have to check if another value is greater than 0.

This code works absolutely fine:

```js
should: [
  { match: { 'ItemResult.ItemAction.Type': 853 } },
  { match: { 'ItemResult.ItemAction.Type': 1013 } },
  { match: { 'ItemResult.ItemAction.Type': 1322 } },
  { match: { 'ItemResult.ItemAction.Type': 5845 } }
]
```

It gives me all recipe entries whose `'ItemResult.ItemAction.Type` is either 853, 1013, 1322 or 5845 as expected. The problem comes with this new more complex condition to my `should` array:

```js
range: {
  'ItemResult.ItemAction.Type': { gte: 5100, lte: 5300 },
  'ItemResult.ItemAction.Data0': { gt: 0 }
}, ...
```

Each individual range property works fine, but naturally I'm getting the following error when both are combined like they are above:

> "reason":"[range] query doesn\'t support multiple fields

Is there a way I happily have both ranges considered within the same query without impacting the other `ItemResult.ItemAction.Type` values?

Obviously I can hook into the API a second time to perform the more complex criterion search, but I'm wondering if I can do it all in the one call.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "range": {
                        "ItemResult.ItemAction.Type": {
                            "gte": 5100,
                            "lte": 5300
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range": {
                        "ItemResult.ItemAction.Data0": {
                            "gt": 0
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

`Range` from elasticsearch doesn't support multiple fields but you can use this query for having multiple `range` conditions.